# how to bind a hotkey with preserving its default behaviour

Tags: autohotkey

```
language = de
~Alt & Shift::
~Shift & Alt::
    if (language == "de") {
        language = en
    }
    else {
        language = de
    }
    msgbox % language
Return
```

This is the code Im working on, binding a work to Alt+Shift. But I wanna preserve the default behavior of Alt+Shift which seems to be disabled after this code runs.
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Use `~Alt & ~Shift::` instead of `~Alt & Shift::`.

The tilde `~` prefix makes a hotkey keep its original function. As far as **I** understand,

```
~Alt & Shift::msgbox
```

could be translated into the following:

```
~Alt::    ; Alt enables the detection of a shift press
hotkey, Shift, shift, ON    ; OVERRIDES the normal shift behavior, not keeping it (~Shift)
hotkey, Shift up, shiftUp, ON
return

shift:
msgBox
return

shiftUp:
hotkey, Shift, shift, OFF
hotkey, Shift up, shiftUp, OFF
return
```

. `Alt` is a hotkey and `Shift` also is one, being activated on `Alt` pressure. But that very `Shift` hotkey overwrites any normal shift behaviour.

So, `alt & shift` is actually two different hotkeys combined to one. Each of them needs to be prefixed with its own options.

---

My solution works with another concurring AutoHotkey script. But it seems not with the windows built-in hotkey `shift+alt` aka `alt+shift`. Even if the ahk hotkey trigger looks like that

```
~Alt & ~Shift::
```

, this will STILL override the usual behavior which is Window's language switching mechanism. I do not know the reason behind it, maybe someone else does? I can only think of a (fairly simple) workaround:

```
~Alt & ~Shift::
send {alt down}{shift}{alt up}
; (your other actions)
return
```

In this case, you might even want to remove the `~`'s in order to prevent confusion.

Comment: I mean I used `~Alt & ~Shift::` and reverse (`~Shift  & ~Alt::`) but the first does not change the language (system tray).